# Changing Kivy Slider Value from another screen

Tags: slider, kivy

I'm trying to reset the values of sliders back to 3. I have two sliders with the values 1 - 5, and a step of 1.

I initially set the value to 3. I want to be able to use my sliders, go to the home screen, then set them back to 3. The sliders need to be re-usable after the reset, which is the current problem that I'm stuck on.

Every time that I hit the reset button, the sliders go back to 3, but cannot be moved again... Does anyone have any insight?

Simple code example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider

Builder.load_string('''

<HomeScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "Next Screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "screen1"
        Button:
            text: "If I press this, it will turn the values back to 3"
            on_release:
                app.root.get_screen("screen1").slider1.value = 3
                app.root.get_screen("screen2").slider2.value = 3

<Screen1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: str(slider1.value)
        Slider:
            id: slider1
            max: 5
            min: 1
            value: 3
            step: 1

        Button:
            text: "Next Screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "screen2"
<Screen2>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: str(slider2.value)
        Slider:
            id: slider2
            max: 5
            min: 1
            value: 3
            step: 1
        Button:
            text: "Back to Home Screen"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "homescreen"

<SM>:
    name: "sm"
    id: sm
    HomeScreen:
        name: "homescreen"
        id: hs
    Screen1:
        name: "screen1"
        id: s1
    Screen2:
        name: "screen2"
        id: s2

''')

class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class Screen1(Screen):
    slider1 = Slider

class Screen2(Screen):
    slider2 = Slider

class SM(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        global sm
        sm = SM()
        return sm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need these assignments

```
class Screen1(Screen):
    slider1 = Slider

class Screen2(Screen):
    slider2 = Slider
```

because you assign new sliders to the slider variables.

To access the slider values you have to use ids like this:

```
Button:
    text: "If I press this, it will turn the values back to 3"
    on_release:
        app.root.get_screen("screen1").ids.slider1.value = 3
        app.root.get_screen("screen2").ids.slider2.value = 3
```

That's all...

Comment: Hey embryo, thank you for replying. That absolutely fixed my problem! I didn't think to use the `.ids`. I accepted your answer but cannot upvote it  until I get enough rep, I'm sorry. Take good care, and thanks again!